# Are modern Ms. Pac-Man cabinets distributed with the “fast/speed/speed-up” setting/hack/mod turned on by default?

Tags: ms-pacman

*Ms. Pac-Man* was released as an arcade game in 1982.

Flash forward to 2016: 30+ years later there are tons of new *Ms. Pac-Man* arcade game cabinets out there in bars, arcades and such nowadays that are new yet they all seem to be set on “fast/speed/speed-up” mode where Ms. Pac-Man herself seems to fly across the screen at a crazy rate of speed.

An [example of the “fast/speed/speed-up” version can be seen in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QqJCnRgWsuM) and an example of the [“slow”/original version can be seen in this other video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w1Xon6Z7r8U) for comparison.

In the 1980s, this “fast/speed/speed-up” mode was considered to be an aftermarket hack of the original 1982 hardware called a [“fast/speed/speed-up chip.”](http://www.arcaderestoration.com/Articles/1/Bob+Roberts/14/Pac-ManMs+Pac-Man+Speed-Up+Chip.aspx) But these modern games are 100% new cabinets from an official/legitimate distributor with—one would assume—newer hardware in them.

So are these modern *Ms. Pac-Man* cabinets being distributed by Bally/Midway or Namco with the “fast/speed/speed-up” mode on as a default?

FWIW, discussions seem to exist about the predominance of the “fast/speed/speed-up” version nowadays here on [AtariAge](http://atariage.com/forums/topic/68415-ms-pac-man-question/) and even at the [Arcade Museum](http://forums.arcade-museum.com/showthread.php?t=222930), but no definite answer stating if this somehow a deafault method of play on new cabinets or not.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41481/discussion-on-question-by-jakegould-are-modern-ms-pac-man-cabinets-distributed).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like the Namco 20th and 25th Anniversary cabinets have the Turbo variants of Pac-Man and Ms. Pac-Man, but it is *disabled by factory default*. The turbo variants can be enabled from the service menu [as explained in the owner’s manual for the Ms. Pac-Man/Galaga model 9600](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91jV-XE4ahS.pdf).

Turbo can also be be toggled on by using the following code: After inserting credits, press Left, Right, Left, Right, Up, Up, Up, Fire. If done correctly, you should hear the "wakka" Pac-Man sound [as explained on this Wikipedia page that lists details on *Pac-Man* anniversary arcade machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pac-Man_anniversary_arcade_machines#Class_of_1981_.2F_20_Year_Reunion_.2820th_Anniversary_machine_for_Ms._Pac-Man.29).

The 30th Anniversary *Pac-Man's Arcade Party* also has speed settings in the service menu [as explained in this official operator’s manual](http://www.bmigaming.com/Games/Manuals/namco/pac-man-arcade-party-home-caberet-model-operators-manual-namco.pdf).

Comment: Great detective work! Now it’s still weird that if the turbo mode is disabled by default, why then does it seem like it’s active on pretty much every *Ms. Pac-Man* cabinet out there.

Comment: I agree; anecdotally almost every Ms. Pac-Man I have seen is the Turbo variant. Perhaps some cabinet vendors are enabling Turbo by default. It'd be interesting to know how it came to be so ubiquitous!

Comment: Does the speed up pacman work on the pacman galaga countercade? Cause I tried the code on both and the code doesn't work. Please help me with this